# Add diffrent data types for javascript ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I've got this problem, is there any reasonable way to return in one XHR request two types of data somehow? For example I want to return an html with some data but aside to that some variables in JSON or plain text.

In this case, I'm working on ajax pagination, there is a request with returns html with next results but I also need a integer with total count of results back from the server.

I see two options:

- make another XHR request just to fetch total count from server
- put the data inside html in some attribute

but both of those ways seems not elegant.

Any idea perhaps how this can be achieve?

Comment: And why do not insert your html into json?

Comment: Just stick the integer and the HTML string into an array and json encode that array, send it to the client and use it however you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Return a JSON encoded array.

```
$return = array(
    'html' => '<div><!-- insert a lot of html here --></div>',
    'productId' => 3,
    'someArray' => array(1, 2, 3, 'string')
);
echo json_encode($return);
```

And then in javascript:

```
obj = JSON.parse(data); // data is return from the ajax request.
```